# My kissing gourami having spots. Help!

Tags: health, fish, diseases, skin-condition, gourami

I have 1 kissing gourami. My favorite fish in my aquarium. But few days I noticed that my kissing gourami having black spots on its scales and fins. And my kissing gourami sits at the bottom of the tank for hours. And my kissing gourami doesn't eat pallets either.
Please tell me if he needs medication!
[image: my kissing gourami's photo]

Comment: please post the readings of your water test like ammonia, nitrite and PH. The first thing to do right now is to add 0,3% aquarium salt to your tank. This is to help against nitrite poisoning of your fish. Do not feed your fish until the problem is solved. Is your tank properly cycled before you added fish? Read more about cycling a tank here: https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm Please edit the information into your question, I need the information to answer your question.

Comment: please do not add any medication to your main tank as this will kill the good bacteria and your fish.if you want to medicate your fish you need a separate tank to treat your fish.